# Modify cookie during specific time Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I'm totally new to node.js and what I am trying to acomplish during my task is to create a web page that shows how many times page was loaded for the last minute using node.js and cookies

I found how to create and update a cookie, so I can see it via console in browser(document.cookie), but I can't find a way to stop increasing cookie value after one minute

My current code is

```
 var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
 var express = require("express");

 var app = express();
 app.use(cookieParser());

 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if (!req.cookies) {
        req.cookie('show', "1");
    }
    let count = parseInt(req.cookies['show']);
    count++;
    res.cookie('show', count);
    res.end(`
    <h1>Cookie counter</><br>
    <p>This page was loaded ${count} time(s) in last minute</p>
    `);

 })

 app.listen(8080);
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
 var express = require("express");

 var app = express();
 app.use(cookieParser());

 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   if (!req.cookies['startTime']) req.cookie('startTime', new Date())
   const startTime = new Date(req.cookies['startTime'])
   const expirateTime = new Date((new Date(startTime)).getTime() + 60000)
   if (!req.cookies['show'] || expirateTime < new Date()) {
     req.cookie('startTime', new Date())
     req.cookie('show', "1")
   }
   let count = parseInt(req.cookies['show']);
   count++;
   res.cookie('show', count);
   res.end(`
   <h1>Cookie counter</><br>
   <p>This page was loaded ${count} time(s) in last minute</p>
`);
})

app.listen(8080);
```